# Solution of Simultaneous Equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Here, A, B and C are angles and P,Q,R,S and T are related by the given equations below.
We have P=222.5 and Q=445 and given Equation No.s -

1) A+B=90°

2) A-B=2C

3) P=R(cosA) + S(sinC)

4) Q+S(sinC)=T(cosB)

5) S(cosC)=R(sinA)

6) S(cosC)=T(sinB)

Find Angle C, and the values of R,S and T

---

Comment: From where Comes this system?

Comment: These equations are formed from a problem of engineering mechanics

Comment: I think your system has no Solutions, check it for typos.

Comment: It has solutions, but I m not able to solve it.

Comment: The answers are C= 18°26' ; R=298.5; T=597; S=281.5

Answer (score 0):

From the second equation we get $$C=\frac{A-B}{2}$$ then we get
$$Q+S\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)=T\cos(B)$$ so 
$$T=\frac{Q+S\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}{\cos(B)}$$
with this equation we get $S$ from
$$S\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)=\tan (B)\left(Q+S\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\right)$$
From here we get $S$ and then $T$ and then $R$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: At first i have thought that there are no Solutions,but then i have found These soloutions, have a nice day!